# Which language is better for a stock market-related iPhone app — JavaScript or Objective-C?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c

If I want to make an application for the iPhone that’s related to the stock market, should I use JavaScript or Objective-C?

Answer (score 3):

JS targets websites / web applications. Objective-C is for native apps.

You *could* build a very simple native app as a wrapper with a WebView for a JS-based website but this is discouraged.

So different languages for different targets. No real choice here.

Comment: You don't need to build a native app wrapper; it's already been done (see my response re: phonegap).  There certainly is a choice.

Comment: Downvoting for promoting a third party wrapper? A wrapper is a wrapper... if you program it yourself or use third party code makes little difference. For native apps HTML/JS *is* a second class citizen.

Comment: The question was comparing two development models.  You gave a naked assertion that one is to be discouraged, and you said that there was no real choice to even make.  That's not helpful.

Comment: Not sure you understand the full implications of using phonegap, or what a stock app is about.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C will give you more flexibility and capability. The iOS audience is **very** *discerning* - most of your users will know the difference between a native application written for the iOS platform versus a "Web app" written more generically. A native application is usually more appreciated than a generic one.

That said, going with Web technologies will make it easier to address wider audiences later, like for other platforms like Android or upcoming Windows phone, again in a generic way.

If you have the budget and a long term vision, I recommend that you "go native" - build your app in Objective C.

Comment: I'll second that.  When it comes to iOS or Mac applications, go native or don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using JavaScript to create touch aware web applications (perhaps embedded in an thin application that's mearly a UIWebView wrapper) versus creating native applications in Objective-C, then it's a pretty simple choice. Native applications will always be considerably richer than any UIWebView based app, as the UIKit provides a wide array of UI capabilities which would be difficult to implement in HTML (5 or otherwise) and even then wouldn't have the same degree of polish.

That said, there's no way (yet?) to create native applications in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You could also consider MonoTouch if you're familiar with the .NET stack and C# already.

Comment: Must be something in the water, they got me too.  You might add some more detail about what the pros and cons would be of going w/ MonoTouch.

Answer (score -1):

The [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) project has made significant strides in allowing one to write native-feeling cross-platform Javascript applications that still provide access to native APIs.

If you are interested or experienced with Javascript and if your project is not graphics-intensive (like a game, which I assume it isn't from your description) I would suggest checking out phonegap.  You also gain an easy outlet for targeting Android and other platforms at the same time.